# Looking for a web service allows you to upload via their API and then replies with the file URL

Tags: api, upload

The title says it all. I'm looking for a web service that allows you to upload via their API and then replies with the file URL. Is this something that exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not exactly what you said (A web service: Like a service that some company provides instead of being a software you can install on your machine)

If being provided by someone else is not a strict requirement, and a code that you can install on a server of yours works ok for you, as long is very turn-key, well, I have coded something like that for uploading images: https://github.com/chris-l/urImgAPI

It uses a RESTful API, and is coded on PHP (so it can be used on any cheap host).

I created this API for uploading images, but it can easily be changed to upload any kind of file. (is just removing the gd image manipulation stuff)

The API has a security feature to prevent that a random person could save things on your  server, by requiring a signature. The signature works like this: (this example line is on php)

```
$signature = md5(md5sum(your_image_file) . "your secret key");
```

You never transmit the secret key plain, only the generated signature.

Is very easy to use IMHO. I use it like this on my terminal:

On my `.zshrc` file, I have this function: (But you can turn this to an bash script, or whatever, if you want)

```
uploadpic() {
   signature=`echo -n "$(md5sum $1|awk '{print $1}')"my_secret_key|md5sum|awk '{print $1}'`
   curl http://my-fileserver.com/upload.php -F image=@$1 -F signature=$signature -F user=user -F filename=$1
}
```

With that on its place, I'm able to upload an image by just doing:

```
$ uploadpic someimage.jpg
```

Then I get an XML answer, that is like this:

```
<response success="true" url="http://my-fileserver.com/view.php?file=user/pBfeP&amp;filename=someimage.jpg" md5="52c5e7013c61cbb8c74ddc390d83a0b5" filename="someimage.jpg" thumb="http://my-fileserver.com/view.php?file=user/pBfeP-thumb&amp;filename=thumb-someimage.jpg"/>
```

The `url` attribute is the file URL you wanted.

If it had to be a service provided by some company, I guess this is not what you want, but hey, cheap php hosting is really cheap, and this way you can be certain that they wont delete your images, and keep a backup of everything, etc.

Is released under the AGPL3 license, so check it and I hope it could be useful for you.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for, but I appreciate the contribution. It's a bit over my head, but at least I have a place to start. Thanks Chris.

Comment: No problem! If you are planning to use it, I can help you if you get stuck with something. ;) Check my github profile for contact info.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but maybe it is of use to someone else.

This simple code uploads images to Imgur with an anonymous api key. (create your own key if you decide on using it)

```html
Copy/paste the link when it is uploaded if you can't see the image.
<br><br>
<div>DROP!<button onclick="document.querySelector('input').click()">Or click</button></div>
<input style="visibility: collapse; width: 0px;" type="file" onchange="upload(this.files[0])">

<p>Uploading...</p>
<a id="link">It's online!!!</a>


<style>
    body {text-align: center; padding-top: 100px;}
    div { border: 10px solid black; text-align: center; line-height: 100px; width: 200px; margin: auto; font-size: 40px; display: inline-block;}
    #link, p , div {display: none}
    div {display: inline-block;}
    .uploading div {display: none}
    .uploaded div {display: none}
    .uploading p {display: inline}
    .uploaded #link {display: inline}
    em {position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0}
</style>

<script>

    /* Drag'n drop stuff */
    window.ondragover = function(e) {e.preventDefault()}
    window.ondrop = function(e) {e.preventDefault(); upload(e.dataTransfer.files[0]); }
    function upload(file) {


        if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;
        document.body.className = "uploading";


        var fd = new FormData(); 
        fd.append("image", file); 
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json");
        xhr.onload = function() {
            document.querySelector("#link").href = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data.link;
            document.body.className = "uploaded";
        }
        
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID 14a7704c52e4b75'); /* Please make a new key if you decide on using this */
        
        xhr.send(fd);
    }
</script>
```

http://codepen.io/drduval/pen/jqeygE